# Not able to install Appium 2 in MAC

Tags: testing, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios, automation-testing

I have issue with installing Appium 2 in MAC!

Here what I did:

1. I installed NPM
2. In Mac Terminal executed it:

```
~ % sudo npm install -g appium@next
```

BUT, unfortunately I got it:

```
npm WARN deprecated typedoc-plugin-resolve-crossmodule-references@0.3.3: Upgrade to typedoc >= 0.24 and remove typedoc-plugin-resolve-crossmodule-references from your dependencies

changed 422 packages in 42s

48 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

I tried to check if Appium anyway was been installed by command:

```
appium --version
```

and got it

```
zsh: command not found: appium
```

I really don't know how I can install Appium 2 (I need second version) - thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it has installed properly , this is a just a warning message for a package that in installed which has an dependency on this old version of typedoc

as for appium command not found issue, run below in terminal after updating your username below

Try instal it once without sudo

```
npm install -g appium@next
```

then run the command `appium --version`

Also install appium doctor

```
npm install -g appium-doctor
```

Then run `appium-doctor` (checks if setup is correct on machine)

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands on Bash Shell:

```
npm i -g appium@next
appium -v
appium driver install uiautomator2
```